# How to fix infinite children processes being created after setting rlim_cur to 7

Tags: c, parent-child, children

I would like to limit the child process to 7. I set rlim_cur to 7, but when run the program continuously created children.  I set rlim_cur to 7 between the getrlimit and setrlimit, but can not figure out why the program does not stop creating after it reaches 7.

```
//#include statements

int main() {

        struct rlimit limit;
        int counter = 0;
        errno = 0;
        pid_t pid;
        char buff[8];

        if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &limit) < 0) {
                printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        limit.rlim_cur = 7;

        if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &limit) < 0) {
                printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        while(1) {

                snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%d", ++counter);
                if ((pid = fork())== 0) {

                        printf("child %d: before execl\n", counter);
                        if(execl("./child", "child", buff, NULL) == -1) {
                                printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
                                //exit(1);
                        }
                }
                else if (pid > 0) {
                        if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
                                printf("Error waiting on child: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                exit(1);
                        }

                }

                 else if (pid == -1) {
                        printf("parent: error creating child: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        sleep(2);
                        exit(1);
                }

                printf("Parent: child %d created with pid: %d\n", counter, getpid());
        }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `rlim_cur` is a *soft* limit. Also note that on Linux (if you read [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)) "[t]he `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit is not enforced for processes that have either the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability". So if you're running as `root` there's no limit.

Comment: Not to mention you shouldn't login as root routinely. It should only be used for system administration, and you should preferably use `sudo` to switch to root just for individual commands that need it.

Comment: So how about the program just tracks how many children it has, and avoids creating more than you want it to?